# Where can I download Service Pack 1 for SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, service-pack

Where can I download Service Pack 1 for SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here it is :

- [Service Pack 1 for SharePoint Foundation 2010 (KB2460058)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26640)
- [Service Pack 1 for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2460045)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=26623)

Answer (score 4):

Foundation SP1 - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2460058

Joel Oleson has spelled it out very well, http://www.sharepointjoel.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=453

Comment: Both answers are valuable and good. I wish I could Mark both with Answer. Thank you.